# How to represent a compressor in dashboard

Tags: website-design, information-graphics, data-visualisation, information-design

I am creating a web dashboard and want to display different sections of a [compressor](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1DIMC_enGB874GB874&biw=1536&bih=754&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNSfPbDbKQXCRK1G8OGfeGD6uTv2Aw%3A1574781086291&sa=1&ei=nkDdXZurEYyeUPKhrpgM&q=compressor%20station%20&oq=compressor%20station%20&gs_l=img.3..35i39j0l9.1859600.1860991..1861447...0.0..0.86.618.10......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i8i30.UJHbYX7mVzA&ved=0ahUKEwib8vzZlIjmAhUMDxQKHfKQC8MQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgdii=nNjdg1OKqZm6SM:&imgrc=3_tRw1smJiHyPM:) (oil or gas). Each section has a sensor that Check in/out of the flow of the content in the pipe. Green denotes good and red part means Hot/needs attention. Right now I made 4 sections which I think is very ugly.

[image]

How can I best represent these pipeline sections with the pressure values in my dashboard?

I also tried this, where the green gradient is the pipe and the dotted lines are the sensors in each section:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://batoryart.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/rura-przekrc3b3j-rzut.jpg

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I think OP simply wants a dashboard to display flow values for sections of a pipeline. More like a linear gauge. One of these? http://www.valarm.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Valarm-Tools-Cloud-Web-Dashboards-for-Remotely-Monitoring-Fire-Risk-Weather-Sensors-in-Southern-California-on-Esri-Maps-3.png

Comment: That is too 3D, I would imagine something in terms of graphs plotting (maybe)

Comment: @Luciano pretty much. Have a look at this https://imgur.com/a/jBFKLLD , the solid gradient is pipeline which will change colour depending on if it is cold or warm and dotted lines are sensor. I want to illustrate that better. TBH I suck at color combination and design.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear and added more specific tags, feel free to roll back or add more details if it's not what you meant.

Comment: Might I recommend a book all about making clear and concise infographics? https://medium.com/@jeffhale/five-takeaways-from-the-visual-display-of-quantitative-information-dd36dae35299

Comment: I edited my question with more information and right word.

Comment: This might be better suited to UX? My gut says that, since these are discreet signals, that a waveform graph may not be suitable for real-time (safety) monitoring. Depending on the distances involved, smoothing a graph may give a false impression of what is happening in between samples. So I guess I am suggesting that the original discreet value indicators may be preferable. Perhaps "audio visualization" is a better meta: like spectral FFT with peak indicator where each band is a sensor. ( https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/how-to-analyze-audio-input-spectrum-correctly )